# TYPO3 extension news and realurl

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, realurl

TYPO3 v 7.6.13
News 5.3.1
realurl 2.1.5

I’ve added the stock realurl configuration for ext:news to my site (manual realurl.conf).

And my URLs are reading as:

www.example.com/news/story/news/detail/News/thisismystorytitle

My page tree:

```
Root
-News (News - List)
--Story (News - Detail)
```

My realurl configuration

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']=array (
  'www.mysite.com' => 
  array (
    'init' => 
    array (
      'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile,redirect',
      'emptyUrlReturnValue' => '/',
    ),
    'pagePath' => 
    array (
      'rootpage_id' => '1',
    ),
    'fileName' => 
    array (
      'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => 0,
      'acceptHTMLsuffix' => 1,
      'index' => 
      array (
        'print' => 
        array (
          'keyValues' => 
          array (
            'type' => 98,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
        'preVars' => array(
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'L',
                'valueMap' => array('en'=>0, 'cy'=>1),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),
        ), // end preVars

    'postVarSets' => 
    array (
      '_DEFAULT' => 
      array (

// EXT:news start
'news' => array(
        array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
        ),
        array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
        ),
        array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
                'lookUpTable' => array(
                        'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                        'alias_field' => 'title',
                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                                'strtolower' => 1,
                                'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                        ),
                        'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                        'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                        'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                        'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                        'autoUpdate' => 1,
                        'expireDays' => 180,
                ),
        ),
),
// EXT:news end

      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Grateful if anyone could advise on whats missing or wrong with my setup.

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what you think is wrong?

Comment: The Action and Controller are being written to the url as well as the pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you configuration

```
array(
        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
),
array(
        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
),
```

says, the Variables for action and controller are passed thru.

Appending an valueMap and noMatch you can delete them:

```
array(
        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
        'valueMap' => array(),
        'noMatch' => 'bypass'
),
array(
        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
        'valueMap' => array(),
        'noMatch' => 'bypass'
),
```

Please be aware that this remove these arguments, on pages where the detail action is not default the news details can not be displayed.

Comment: The only problem now is that my url string has gone from

www.mysite.com/news/story/news/detail/News/thisismystorytitle
to
www.mysite.com//story/news/News/thisismystorytitle

Comment: Try to clear the real_url and TYPO3 cache. In my opinion the changes from above should not lead to this behaivor. Check if you maybe forgot an comma or an brace.

Comment: No luck so far, I've cleared down both sets of cache and checked my realurlconf for any syntax errors too.